# How to use an if statement in SAS for a variable value of format x.x

Tags: if-statement, format, sas

I am trying to use a series of if and else statements, for :

```
if var1 = 1 then var2 = "day 1";

else if var1 = 2 then var2 = "day 2";
```

The above bit works fine.

Then I have values for `var1` of 1.1 and 1.2 and 2.1 etc. What I would like is that, if the value of `var1` is of the format x.x (a value with one decimal place) then `var2 = "No day assigned"`.

I am unsure how to program that in SAS?

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean if the value is formatted with 4.1, or do you mean if the value is not a round integer?  6 can be expressed with the format 4.1 as 6.0, after all.

Comment: @joe , I meant, if the value is not a round integer, so if it's 9.01 rather than 9 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the MOD function to determine if var1 is an integer or not.  If your logic above applies to all values (i.e. the day number is the same as var1), then you can also simplify your if statements to a single line.

```
data test;
input var1;
length var2 $15;
var2=ifc(mod(var1,1)=0,cats('day ',var1),'No day assigned');
cards;
1
2
1.1
2.1
3
4
;
run;
```

Comment: I believe that `DATALINES` is perferred over `CARDS`. [*Veteran SAS users may be familiar with the original name for this keyword: CARDS. CARDS is a throwback to the early days of data processing, when routines and data were fed into the computer via physical punched cards.*](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi31/228-31.pdf)

Comment: @keith , That answers my question brilliantly, thanks! I have not used the mod or ifc function before so good to learn! I used: if mod(var1 , 1) ne 0 then var2 = "No day assigned", as the ifc would not work for the actual values in the dataset, but will use in future!

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with CARDS versus DATALINES - they have the same result.  They do show your age, of course...

Comment: Ellie, you might want to use a custom built format rather than a bunch of IF statements if the CATS doesn't actually work; ie, rather than `if var1=1 then var2='something'; else if var1=2 then var2='something else'; ... ` is much harder to write and harder to maintain than `PROC FORMAT; value myf 1='something' 2='something else'; quit;  then var2=put(var1,MYF.);` in the data step.

Comment: Just for the record, my use of CARDS is less of an age thing (although some may dispute that), more of being a lazy typist! :)